# jquery - required help in array function

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have an array like this.

```
[{"label":"2013-12-01","value":"2372"},{"label":"2014-01-01","value":"2458"},{"label":"2014-02-01","value":"1636"},{"label":"2014-03-01","value":"2527"},{"label":"2014-04-01","value":"2129"},{"label":"2014-05-01","value":"149"}]
```

I'm creating a line chart using `highcharts`.

Data excepted format for line chart is

```
[["2013-12-01",2372],["2014-01-01",2458],["2014-02-01",1636],["2014-03-01",2527],["2014-04-01",2129],["2014-05-01",149]]
```

I got no idea on how to do it.

Actually the result is from a ajax result.

I get the result in `Object Object` and I converted it using `JSON.stringify`. But after converting I get both label and value.

Someone help me out to get the data in the chart expected format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need trivial foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the current array and return each label inside it into a new array etc

```
var new_arr = $.map(arr, function(itm) { return [itm.label, itm.value]; });
```

Comment: I'm getting result like this `["2013-12-01", "2372", "2014-01-01", "2458", "2014-02-01", "1636", "2014-03-01", "2527", "2014-04-01", "2129", "2014-05-01", "149"]`.

Comment: Thanks I did edit that function a bit and I got the desired result. `var new_arr = JSON.stringify($.map(arr, function(itm) { return [[itm.label, itm.value]]; }));`

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript's native [**Array.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, similar to this:

```
var y = x.map(function(item){
    return [item.label, item.value];
})
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7jk7f/) - Using Array.map

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
var orgArr = [{"label":"2013-12-01","value":"2372"},{"label":"2014-01-01","value":"2458"},  {"label":"2014-02-01","value":"1636"},{"label":"2014-03-01","value":"2527"},{"label":"2014-04-01","value":"2129"},{"label":"2014-05-01","value":"149"}]
var newArr = []
$.each(orgArr, function( index, value ) {
  newArr.push([value.label, value.value]);
});
console.log(newArr)
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WBbW/) for above code